# LD_PRELOAD multiple interdependent libraries

Tags: shared-libraries, ld, dynamic-library, ld-preload

I Have Libraries with a tree of dependencies, i.e. some of the dependencies have other dependencies I want to Preload. How can I do this?

```
LD_PRELOAD \
/opt/yocto/2.5.1/sysroots/core2-64-poky-linux/usr/lib/libicudata.so.60 \
/opt/yocto/2.5.1/sysroots/core2-64-poky-linux/usr/lib/libicuuc.so.60 \
/opt/yocto/2.5.1/sysroots/core2-64-poky-linux/usr/lib/libicui18n.so.60 \
/opt/yocto/2.5.1/sysroots/core2-64-poky-linux/usr/lib/libQt5Core.so.5 \
MyApp
```

The `LD_PRELOAD` call contains is sorted, such that the dependencies are listed before the depending library.

The Linker throws the following error:

```
ERROR: ld.so: object '/opt/yocto/2.5.1/sysroots/core2-64-poky-linux/usr/lib/libQt5Core.so.5' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
```

Can the libraries be preloaded to fulfil the dependencies in the correct order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error:

```
ld.so: object '/opt/yocto/2.5.1/sysroots/core2-64-poky-linux/usr/lib/libQt5Core.so.5' \
from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.
```

means that the dynamic loader tried to open the library and failed.

There are several possible reasons for this failure:

1. The file doesn't exist (use `ls -L /opt/yocto/2.5.1/sysroots/core2-64-poky-linux/usr/lib/libQt5Core.so.5` to confirm that it does
2. The file is for the wrong architecture (e.g. 32-bit ELF when `MyApp` is 64-bit, or vice versa). Use `file MyApp` and `file libQt5Core.so.5` to confirm that they match.
3. Something else. Perhaps `MyApp` was linked with `newlib` or `uClibc`, but `libQt5Core.so.5` was built with GLIBC (or vice versa).

Comment: In my case the library can't be preloaded because it itself requires a dynamic library which is "not found" in the LD_LIBRARY_PATH. Unfortunate I can't change the LD_LIBRARY_PATH to include the dependencies.

Comment: @danba I am confused: if you know the reason `libQt5Core` is not loading, why didn't you say so, and why don't you add whatever library it requires to the `LD_PRELOAD` list?

Comment: I was trying to explain that the shared Library is missing dependencies in the question. The LD_PRELOAD list in the question does contain all dependencies, they're just not interpreted correctly it seems.

Comment: @danba Your theory of why this doesn't work is probably incorrect. How do you *know* that "the library can't be preloaded because it itself requires a dynamic library which is "not found"" ? Setting `LD_DEBUG=files,libs` could provide additional info.

Comment: Thanks for the `LD_DEBUG=files,libs` suggestion. It turns out the environment was dirty on that machine. Your answer, by the way, summarizes possible issues nicely.